# STM32 blinking LED wrong register?

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller

Has anyone an idea why the code doesn't work?

```
RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN;
GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0x3u << 6u);
GPIOB->MODER |= (0x1u << 6u);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    GPIOB->ODR |= (0x1u << 0x3u);
}
```

I'm using a STM board (STM32L432KC) which has an integrated LED that is called pin PB3 (Port 26) but after flashing nothing happens. Actually there should shine a LED. Do I use the right register?

Comment: you are not blinking the led with that code and you dont have a delay in there anyway.  depending on how your board is designed you may need to make the pin low to turn the led on.  you can use the bsrr register and you can just use GPIOB->BSRR = 1<<3 and then try 1<<(3+16).  and to blink use those two register bits with a delay in between

Comment: assuming that all the magic numbers, the structure and defines are correct per the manual then you are doing the steps needed to set up the port, correctly and that is the minimum required.

Comment: Thank you but why I've to do the second shift 1 << (3+16)?

Comment: one sets bit 3 the other sets bit 19, if you look at the bsrr register you see that one bit makes that pin high one makes it low.  one of the two high or low will turn the led on the other off.  so i fyou want to blink it as in your title question, then you need to go on and off at human speed.

Comment: if your code is not turning the led on then as mentioned try making the pin low and see if that makes the led go on.  Have you looked at the schematic?  What does it show?

Comment: what does the disassembly of both this section and the vector table show?  (will ultimately confirm the register addresses being used and how).

Comment: To you mean the main.S file?

Comment: no, disassembly of the binary that helps show if your vector table is right and the part is booting correctly, if the register addressing is right, etc.

Comment: if you had indicated the board being a nucleo, and that would have shown that 1 on the pin turns the led on, and that the led was turning on for you, but not turning off (blinking) that would have more directly lead to an answer instead of us guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting a bit in the `ODR` but never clearing it, so it won't flash, you will need a delay between on/off transitions to be able to visibly see it flashing.

It's good practice to write to the `BSRR` register instead of the `ODR` too where possible, this allows you to avoid read-modify-write cycles.

If that code is your whole `main()` then you might want to replace the `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)` with a `while(1)`, you generally don't want to return from `main` in an embedded context.

Comment: Thank you very much! but the LED isn't still flashing. Actually it isn't even glowing. Do I am on the right path how I'm using the register addresses? The LED is as said PB3. Maybe the LED is only damaged?

Comment: Is this a commercially available board, what board is it?

Comment: It's  STM32 by ST NUCLEO-L432KC Nucleo Development Board. The schematic shows PB3 as green LED.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence is wrong (I did not check if you use the correct RCC register)

```
RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN;
GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0x3u << 6u);
```

When you enable the peripheral clock you need to readback the value or add some delay your changes to propagate through the bus. I usually use the barrier instruction for that.

```
RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN;
__DMB();
GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0x3u << 6u);
```

If you do not add this delay (or readback) the first opearation will fail as it will be performed on the non clocked GPIO periperal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, makes sense! I've add this line but the it's still nothing happens (I checked the pin already).

Comment: I found the problem it executes the program only once (I push this problem in another thread cause the title problem is solved).

Comment: Never had that problem with any of these parts, this is C code, plenty of delay.  Technically possible with some designs, but not the STM32s.

Comment: I found the problem. Seems like I have only to push the start/restart button (after pushing it works).

Comment: @old_timer I afraid you do not have too much experience with stm32. Read the Referance Manual RCC section of **any** STM32.  And the remark about the plenty of time in C code does not make any sense.

Comment: dozens of different stm32 chips, almost every family. countless custom chips and fpgas, etc with special timing...Im sorry you dont understand.

Comment: right per that document, this code is written in C...so more than two clocks, done, no need to read anything.

Comment: even if asm you would have to specifically put effort into violating that timing intentionally arranging the instructions and then you cant guarantee that you violate it .

Comment: yes, a read will insure it in most designs (not all)(in general), but can be overkill.  Wasnt the problem here clearly, for product firmware the read back is a good idea to insure the timing is exceeded.  calling a bx lr function from C would also exceed it as well.

Comment: If you worded your answer as being free advice rather than this is the problem because from experience you should know it wasnt, then that would have been fine.

Comment: I have a board on order, will try it out.

Comment: @old_timer it well known issue using the STM32s. I am surpised that you have not heard about it. If you access the peripheral befoe the clock is set, the next accesses to the registers can be also wrong.  For example STM in low level driver does the readback

Comment: `#define __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE()   do { \
                                        __IO uint32_t tmpreg = 0x00U; \
                                        SET_BIT(RCC->AHB1ENR, RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN);\
                                        /* Delay after an RCC peripheral clock enabling */ \
                                        tmpreg = READ_BIT(RCC->AHB1ENR, RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN);\
                                        UNUSED(tmpreg); \
                                          } while(0U)`